# Inline::Java inside of Perl Threads: unknown java object reference)

Tags: java, perl

I try to run java-code inside of Perl - using Inline::Java

Working all very well - but not when I have Theads in place.

**x.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib ".";
use MyP;

use Inline Java => <<'END_OF_JAVA_CODE';
class MyX
{
    public MyX () {}

    public static int foo (int a)   // static
    {
        return a+1;
    }
    
    public int bar (int b)
    {
        return b*2;
    }
}
END_OF_JAVA_CODE

my $myx = new MyX ();

print "\n1) " . MyX->foo (3);    # ok
print "\n2) " . $myx->bar (4);   # ok
my $myp = MyP->new ($myx);       
print "\n3) " . $myp->x1 ();     # ok
print "\n4) " . $myp->x2 ();     # ok

$myp->start ();                  # NOK
for (;;)
{
    sleep (1);
}
print "\n";
```

**MyP.pm**

```
package MyP;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};

    $self->{myx} = shift;
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub x1
{
    my $self = shift;
    return MyX->foo (6);
}

sub x2
{
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{myx}->bar (7);
}


sub start
{
    my $self = shift;
    threads->create (\&run, $self);
}
        
sub run
{
    my $self = shift;
    print "\nT1) " . MyX->foo (10);          # static
    print "\nT2) " . $self->{myx}->bar (20); # by instance
}
1;
```

**Output**

```
1) 4
2) 8
3) 7
4) 14
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Unknown Java object reference main::MyX=HASH(0x55dd5252bee8) at MyP.pm line 45 thread 1.
 at MyP.pm line 45 thread 1.
```

As we can see calling it directly is fine, calling it inside of a package/class works also. But if I calling it inside a Thread there is some problem.

I try it with an instance I pass or the static way.

Comment: Please describe why you need this functionality (passing a Inline::Java object to a thread)

Comment: I just need to call Java inside of a Perl-Thread. It is not working - even with the static method. So I thought maybe I need to pass it into the thread. If it would work I see also no need to pass it to the thread.

Comment: Added an issue at the GitHub issue tracker here: https://github.com/ingydotnet/Inline-Java/issues/13

Comment: You can work around some modules that aren't thread safe by loading it from within the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub! I tried the mailinglist but it seems to be down. I tried also loading it inside the threads run but it did not work either.

I just put the use Inline::Jave .... inside the run sub.

Comment: Why not use Java threads instead?

Comment: My requirement is much bigger than you see in the sample. I try to outsource task to Java - but these tasks are located in threads.